# Bibliography: Remove dot between (book)title and series

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have to ask again in order to get the bibliography format I need for my paper – unfortunately, this won’t be the last question :D

It’s about the dot between the (book)title and the series. How can I remove it?

[image]

So in the example above it actually should be "*Semiotik / Semiotics. 2. Teilband* (Handbücher zur Sprach- und Kommunikationswissenschaft)".

You can see my try in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear, innamebeforetitle=true, innameidem=true, maxcitenames=2, dashed=false]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{sortname}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addspace\slash\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias*[bib]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\adddot\space}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\slash}
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\slash}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \bibstring{in}%
  \printunit{\intitlepunct}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addnbthinspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\urlstyle{same}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{URL: <\url{#1}>}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  editor  = {Hrsg\adddot},
  editors = {Hrsg\adddot},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{superedition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[\blx@delimcontext labeldate]{%
       \printfield[superedition]{edition}%
       \global\clearfield{edition}%
       \iflabeldateisdate
         {\printdateextra}
         {\printlabeldateextra}}}}
\makeatother

\DeclareFieldFormat{series}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{booktitle+series}{%
    \printfield{booktitle}%
    \setunit{\space}%
    \printfield{series}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@incollection{Baldinger,
author = {Baldinger, Kurt},
title = {Semasiologie und Onomasiologie},
booktitle = {2. Teilband},
publisher = {De Gruyter Mouton},
year = {2008},
editor = {Posner, Roland and Robering, Klaus and Sebeok, Thomas},
edition = 3
series = Handbücher zur Sprach- und Kommunikationswissenschaft 13/2
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{literatur}

\begin{document}

\cite{Baldinger}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

There has to be something wrong with `renewbibmacro*{booktitle+series}{…}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no bibmacro called `booktitle+series`. More generally, there need not be a bibmacro for every possible combination of fields.

Ultimately, the presentation in the bibliography is controlled by a bibliography driver. For your style (`style=ext-authoryear,` and indeed all `biblatex-ext` styles) the drivers live in [`ext-standard.bbx`](https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-ext/blob/release/ext-standard.bbx). The relevant driver for `@incollection` can be found in [ll. 355-386 [v0.13]](https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-ext/blob/9d79bafff65174186d3f99ad7282381f0b40bb3e/ext-standard.bbx#L355-L386). The bit that prints the series is in `incollection:parent` ([ll. 388-405 [v0.13]](https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-ext/blob/9d79bafff65174186d3f99ad7282381f0b40bb3e/ext-standard.bbx#L388-L405)) and it has

```
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
```

The easiest way to influence the formatting of the `series` is to modify that bibmacro.

For your needs

```
\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{series}%
       \setunit*{\sernumdelim}%
       \printfield{number}}}%
  \newunit}
```

should do the right thing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  innameidem=true,
  maxcitenames=2,
  dashed=false,
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{sortname}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\slash}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addspace\slash\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\adddot\space}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \bibstring{in}%
  \printunit{\intitlepunct}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addnbthinspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\urlstyle{same}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{URL: <\url{#1}>}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  editor  = {Hrsg\adddot},
  editors = {Hrsg\adddot},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{superedition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[\blx@delimcontext labeldate]{%
       \printfield[superedition]{edition}%
       \global\clearfield{edition}%
       \iflabeldateisdate
         {\printdateextra}
         {\printlabeldateextra}}}}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{series}%
       \setunit*{\sernumdelim}%
       \printfield{number}}}%
  \newunit}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Baldinger,
  author    = {Baldinger, Kurt},
  title     = {Semasiologie und Onomasiologie},
  maintitle = {Semiotik / Semiotics},
  booktitle = {2.~Teilband},
  publisher = {De Gruyter Mouton},
  year      = {2008},
  editor    = {Posner, Roland and Robering, Klaus and Sebeok, Thomas},
  edition   = 3,
  series    = {Handbücher zur Sprach- und Kommunikationswissenschaft},
  number    = {13/2},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Baldinger}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Baldinger, Kurt ( 3 2008). „Semasiologie und Onomasiologie“, in: Posner, Roland / Robering, Klaus / Sebeok, Thomas (Hrsg.). Semiotik / Semiotics. 2. Teilband (Handbücher zur Sprach- und Kommunikationswissenschaft 13/2). De Gruyter Mouton.]

Note that I changed the

```
  series = Handbücher zur Sprach- und Kommunikationswissenschaft 13/2
```

in the `.bib` file to

```
  series    = {Handbücher zur Sprach- und Kommunikationswissenschaft},
  number    = {13/2},
```

Non-numeric values without braces will cause errors and the number of the book in the series should go into the `number` field. Note also that I added the missing

```
  maintitle = {Semiotik / Semiotics},
```